# Can i get onClickListener for this list listed by CustomAdapter?

Tags: android, listener, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have listed a list with custom adapter to display different images in each list item and succeeded. 
Now i need to add a onitemclick listener for that list.
Unable to access the id because the list id is - "@+id/android:list".
Unable to identify this id.

Any ideas please share.
You will get some more idea when you see this below link

[Click here for the example i tried.](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/04/custom-widget-adapters.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given example, the ListActivity is extended in CustomAdapterActivity.java

so its simple to get Click events of the list items by writing list item click listener

and to write onClickListener you need to do

like this in that class.

**

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    }
```

**

**And To Know More and Learn About LIST VIEW in Android you can view this :** http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing is now i need to add a button in all my listitems with two click events for each listitems. one is button click and list item click. But i am able to get only the button click and the list item click is getting disabled. is there any option to have click for both.

Comment: @Arun yes its posiible, you just need to check for custom list view Q-A in stack overflow and you will easily find your solution..and if still you dont get it..you can start new question.