# ListActivity Won't Display

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

In the following app the tabs will show correctly but I can't determine why the list view doesn't show.  Any ideas on to help.  It doesn't crash but I do get an error code:  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
10-14 20:27:32.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dana/com.dana.DanaHillsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dana/com.dana.RSSView}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Class to be launched code:

```
public class RSSView extends ListActivity {

    private static RssListAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        List<JSONObject> jobs = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        try {
            jobs = RssReader.getLatestRssFeed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
        }


        Log.d("id", "log this");
        adapter = new RssListAdapter(this,jobs);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


        setContentView(R.layout.rssview1);



    }
}
```

Main Code:

```
public class DanaHillsActivity extends TabActivity {


    public static TabHost tabHost; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        /** TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
        /** TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */



        firstTabSpec.setIndicator("1").setContent(new Intent(this,RSSView.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator("2").setContent(new Intent(this,RSSView.class));
        thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("3").setContent(new Intent(this,RSSView.class));

        /** Add tabSpec to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
    }
}
```

Main .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

rssview1.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/wallpaper">

    <!-- List view -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:divider="#00000000" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setContentView(R.layout.rssview1);` needs to come before the lines that set the list adapter. Try placing `setContentView(R.layout.rssview1);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: It still doesn't work even if I change it to before the lines that set the list adapter.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't notice your error before, but in your layout xml file your ListView id should be `android:id="@android:id/list"` instead of `android:id="@+id/android:list"`

Comment: Sorry it was none of the issues.  The issue was that I forgot to add a permission to use the internet.  Look at my name and know that this is my first android app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using List actvity then no need of setting `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);`
remove it.I think your list is created but it not showing because your layout overwrite this view.
 so once remove that line   `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);`

Answer (score 0):

You are extending ListActivity so you dont need to take any listview from the xml.

you can get listview object like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753765/can-i-get-onclicklistener-for-this-list-listed-by-customadapter/7753873#7753873)

and use that to set adapter.